# Forge not generating master view

Tags: python, autodesk-forge, bim

I've been trying to use the forge viewer and I cannot get it to translate the .rvt files with the room info.
I read you need to specify: "generateMasterViews": True and in the headers 'x-ads-force: true'
What am I doing wrong??? here is my code:

```
model_url='modelderivative/v2/designdata/job'
urn=json.loads(r_file.text)["objectId"]
print(urn)
urn_b=base64.b64encode(bytes(urn,'ascii'))
urn1=urn_b.decode('ascii')

headers4={
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            "x-ads-force": 'true'
        }
format_type = 'svf';
format_views = ['2d','3d'];
data4={
        'input': {
            'urn': urn1
        },
        'output': {
            'formats': [
                {
                    'type': format_type,
                    'views': format_views
                },
            ],
            "advanced": {
                "generateMasterViews": True
            }

        }
    }
r_model=requests.post(base_url+model_url,headers=headers4,data=json.dumps(data4))
r_model.text
```

Comment: May I know what the Revit version of your model is? Could you try other tools (e.g. postman) to submit the REST API call? if your Revit version is not too old, then it's probably that the above code snippet cannot send the correct job configuration in the body.

Comment: I've tried uploading 2021 and 2022 versions of rvt.

Comment: Could you try the sample models from [Revit Sample Project Files](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html) to test your code?

Comment: I ended up doing it with the forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app. That worked after making the file a bit lighter. But no, even with the sample project it wouldn't create an svf with room info.

Comment: That's strange ... Could you test with this vscode extension, and submit the master view transition by clicking the `translate object (custom)`?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools

Comment: if you want to discuss this online, you may book a meeting here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/the-doctor-is-in